# Determine if Android battery is currently LOW

Tags: android, batterymanager

I'm aware that I can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` and `ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY` which will notify my app when this battery LOW state **changes**, but how can I determine if the battery is **currently** LOW or OKAY?

`BatteryManager` may allow me to get the current percentage and status, but it doesn't appear to expose a status for LOW.

Comment: can you please post you BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 1):

The [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) broadcast is a sticky broadcast. And one of the extras is [ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW).

So this little method should do what you need

```
private boolean isBattteryLow() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, filter);
    return batteryIntent.getBooleanExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_BATTERY_LOW, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know at what percentage the system is sending you the `LOW` status it would probably be best to register the `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` broadcast receiver in the manifest and calculate the percentage from `BatteryManager` when you get the `LOW` event, save it and use it later to determine `LOW` status based on the data you can get from `BatteryManager`.

Since the `LOW` broadcast is not sticky I guess it is the only way.

I think most of the devices send `LOW` event at 15%, so it would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! This occurred to me, but I was hoping for a better way as this would require me to either get the battery warning level configured for the device (which `BatteryService` does when deciding to broadcast the LOW / OKAY actions) or as you suggest, make up my own threshold which may not agree with the system.

It's rather annoying that LOW / OKAY seemingly can't be queried...